# Issues when upgrading Moodle to its latest version 4.3

Tags: sql-server, upgrade, moodle, sql-server-collation

I'm hoping somebody could shed some light to the following error that happen when I try to upgrade Moodle. After the usual checklist have been performed and passed without any note, I clicked on the Begin Upgrade button but this error message appears.
Based on the message, I can only guess it has something to do with my database collation, but there hasn't been any issue with it before (I've performed version upgrades before to the same moodle instance at least 5 times).

Many thanks in advance for the assistance.

[image]

Comment: [please don't load imahes of code errors and much more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: That seems to imply that the collation is missing from the database?

Comment: Ok, so which version of SQL Server are you running that has `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AI`? If I execute `SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() WHERE [name] LIKE N'SQL[_]Latin1[_]General[_]CP1[_]%';` against SQL Server 2014, 2016, 2017, 2019 and 2022 they only list the collations `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI`, `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, that's what I got too. (thank you for pointing me the command btw). So it must be a bug in the moodle code then?